# using methods from another class without needing to use the class name

Tags: c#, namespaces

As you can find in the c# documentation

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

**System** is a namespace and **Console** is a class in that namespace. The using keyword can be used so that the complete name is not required, as in the following example:

```
using System;
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
Console.WriteLine("World!");
```

I'm trying to apply this to my code so I can use a method in a helper class `HelperClass` from another class without the need to use the class name `HelperClass.HelperMethod();`

Like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sample.Helpers
{
    public static class HelperClass
    {
        public static void HelperMethod()
        {
            // Do something here
        }

    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Sample.Helpers;


    namespace Sample
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // call HelperMethod
                HelperMethod();
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, the `HelperMethod()` is not found by the compiler

I have seen some tutorials code using this, but I have not yet find out what I'm missing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the following:

```
using static Sample.Helpers.HelperClass;
```

This will allow you to use the static members of `HelperClass` without qualifying them with the class name.

More information on [`using static` directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static).